# WordPress- GEO based Web Pages

Tags: wordpress, redirect, indexing, geolocation

I want a solution for there are two diffrent home pages one for indian users and another one is for the international users, what will be the solution for doing it with or without plugin without chaching issue as well.

I was using js to get the ip and fetched the location, International it is running smoothly but when it is redirecting to the indian userdomain.com/in so is taking some time to fecth the location due to this indian user may see intenational home page as well.

hosting in Namecheap and DNS is from Microsoft .